# Automatically close the execution of a jar file or automatically run a jar file on an event

Tags: java, jar, raspberry-pi, autorun, auto-close

I have implemented an application that process some xml input files and write more xml files as result.

I have to put this jar to run on a Raspberry Pi.

I transfer the input files from my pc to Raspberry Pi using PuTTY or WinSCP.

I have a method that read from a directory whose path I specified all the names of .xml files as filename.xml and add them into a list. Then I call other methods that process the inputFile on position 0 in list.

The inputFile is the file denoted by "path+filename".

After processing the inputFile from the position 0 in list, I delete the inputFile, and then the name from list.

My app should run permanently because the inputFiles may be sent at any time.
  **Here is the first problem: I don't know how to make my jar permanently run.**

**Another problem is when there are no more files to read, because if the jar is still running, there an error will be thrown, because there are no more files.**

*I think I need my app to run only if there are xml file in the directory I set on Raspberry Pi, and I don't know hot to make it happen... There should be a trigger or something that make my app running only when xml files are sent to raspberry pi.*

Answer (score 0):

Let's say incoming file is in variable `filename` with path `path` as you told.
We can wait until this file exists like this:

```
File f = new File(path+filename);
while(true){ //infinite loop for infinite executing
    while(!f.exists()){
        Thread.sleep(10000); //long time is ok (10 seconds)
    }
    readFile(f); //your code to read file
    //I recommend to delete or rename file to let f vaiable
}
```

To use it for folder you can use this:

```
File f = new File(path);
while(true){ //infinite loop for infinite executing
    while(f.listFiles().length==2){ //contains only . and .. "files"
        Thread.sleep(10000); //long time is ok (10 seconds)
    }
    readFolder(f.listFiles()); //your code to read folder (array of files)
}
```

And a bit better way to find out there is new file in folder added:

```
File f = new File(path);
int lastCount=2; //or =f.listFiles().length to skip change at start
while(true){ //infinite loop for infinite executing
    while(f.listFiles().length==lastCount){
        Thread.sleep(10000); //long time is ok (10 seconds)
    }
    readFolder(f.listFiles()); //your code to read folder (array of files)
    lastCount=f.listFiles().length; //setting we have just know how many files are there
}
```

Not tested, will work for every types of files, not only `.xml`. Filter should not cause much problems.